# how to delete single value from Cloud Firestore Array in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.ios

[image]

I am trying to delete the single `"/UsersPublic/cqLJfFg6buXVRf2oB51PwEE01u52"` value from within my `"Followers"` array in Cloud Firestore.

Here is my code:

```
this.collectionRef = Firestore.SharedInstance.GetCollection("UserFollowers");
this.docReference = this.collectionRef.GetDocument(UserId);
var deleteData = new Dictionary<object, object> { { $"UsersPublic/cqLJfFg6buXVRf2oB51PwEE01u52", FieldValue.Delete } };
this.docReference.UpdateData(deleteData, (error) =>
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Error updating document: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
        return;
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine("Document successfully updated!");

});
```

But it's not working, how this can be done in Xamarin.iOS?

> Note: The field type is not string its reference type value

**I'm getting this exception:**

[image]

Comment: Have you got error?

Comment: no, but field from the cloud firestore not removed

Comment: You could  invoke  `FieldValue.delete()` method when you update a document. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields .

Comment: I have check that and applied, but as I have mentioned it's of reference type. And I have performed this step but not get the success, I have done this too this.collectionRef = this.GetCollectionRef();
                    this.docReference = this.collectionRef.GetDocument(UserId);

                    var keys = new NSObject[]
                    {
                        new NSString($"/UserPublic/{follower.Id}"),
                    };
                    var objects = new NSObject[]
                    {
                        FieldValue.Delete,
                    };

Comment: You would better post the issue to google official forums .

Comment: did you got the solution?